# Button only appears or becomes enabled when user scores a certain figure?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button form where a numerical value is attributed to each selection.  The score is totaled up at the end of the form.  A user needs to score a certain amount in order to submit an application.

I have the submit button disabled in the html.  I need it to enable only when the user scores over 60.  I have tried a few variations of the code but the button just remains disabled.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
  </li>

  <p>Total Score:<span id="total">0</span></p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" 
   class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton" disabled/>
   </form>
   </body>

  <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

  <script language="javascript">
  $(":radio").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
      total += Number(this.value);
    });

    $("#total").text(total);
  });

  //ENABLE SUBMIT BUTTON CODE ACCORDING TO SCORE
 function submitOnly() {
 var current = $('.total').filter(':checked');

 if (current.score >= 60) {
sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
 }
 };
 </script>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery, you can make a check every time the score changes like so:

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    total += Number(this.value);
    if (total > 60) {
      $("#SubmitButton").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  $("#total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<p>Total Score:<span id="total">0</span></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton" disabled />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have no need to declare btn variable

Comment: Legend, @KobanDavis!  Again, Thank you so much for your help.  Lifesaver!  @IgorMelekhov, Thank you also for your input!

Comment: No problem, if you ever need help again, let me know  